# Python, html and writing to a text file

Tags: python

I'm creating an html string and writing it to a an .html file. I'm pulling data from websites with json and xml. This pulls text and links and places them into a triple quoted string. There is more to this html string but this much will show the problem. I have a function that takes the news string and writes the string to a .html file. I know that all the inserting of the data works because before I send the string to the write to file function I have it print to screen and have copied it to a text file and displayed it on the browser and it displays properly with all the correct data. The problem occurs when python writes to the file. I get a "has to be string error".

It was writing to the file just fine when the only data was text but once it started to be urls it would fail to write. Well, it would not fell to write every single time but once is enough.

I have a theory. Some urls contain escape characters or some such(haven't been programming too long). Or maybe the data that I'm inserting need to be put in triple quotes before inserting it to the html string. I'm not sure that is even possible.

I have tried inserting the data using this: news % (data,data,data) but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
news = ("""<div id='weather'>""" +
   """<center><h1>Weather</h1></center>""" +
   """<center><cite>Weatherunderground</cite></center>""" +        
   """<hr />""" +
   """<h6>""" + weather['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]['title'] + """</h6>""" +
   """<p>""" + weather['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]['fcttext'] + """</p>""" +
   """<h6>Forecast</h6>"""
   """<table border='1'>"""
   """<tr>"""
   """<th style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['date']['weekday'] + """</th>""" +
   """<th style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][1]['date']['weekday'] + """</th>""" +
   """<th style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][2]['date']['weekday'] + """</th>""" +
   """<th style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][3]['date']['weekday'] + """</th>""" +
   """</tr>""" +
   """<tr>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>""" + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions'] + """</td>""" +
   """</tr>""" +
   """<tr>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>high """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>high """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>high """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>high """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """</tr>""" +
   """<tr>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>low """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>low """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>low """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """<td style='font-size: small;'>low """ + weather['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit'] + """</td>""" +
   """</tr>""" +
   """</table>""" +
   """</div>""" +
   """<hr />""" +
   """<div id='kindle'>""" +
   """<center><h1>Amazon Daily Kindle Deal</h1></center>""" +
   """<center><cite>amazon</cite></center>""" +
   """<hr />""" +
   """<div class='firstHeadline'>""" +
   """<h3>""" + kind[0][0] + """</h3>""" +
   """<p class='content'>""" + kind[1][0] + """</p>""" +
   """<p class='url'><a href='""" + kind[2][0] + """'>""" + kind[2][0] + """</a></p>""" +
   """</div>""" +
   """<hr />""" +
   """</div>""" +
   """<div id='amazonApp'>""" +
   """<center><h1>Amazon App of the Day</h1></center>""" +
   """<center><cite>amazon</cite></center>""" +
   """<hr />""" +
   """<div class='firstHeadline'>""" +
   """<h3>""" + app[0][0] + """</h3>""" +
   """<p class='content'>""" + app[1][0] + """</p>""" +
   """<p class='url'><a href='""" + app[2][0] + """'>""" + app[2][0] + """</a></p>""" +
   """</div>""" +
   """<hr />""" +
   """</div>""")
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, could you post them?

Comment: I am getting an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 3471: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Sigh. This is a FAQ. Search for "UnicodeEncodeError ascii codec". Read this: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Please use a templating library instead of building HTML like that. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

Comment: @FogleBird: If you can make an answer out of that, I'd upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure without seeing the input data, but it's likely because some of them are numbers (`int`, `float`) or possibly `unicode` (which would yield a `UnicodeEncodeError`).

The simplest thing to do would be to wrap all the variables in `str(…)` or `unicode(…)`, but if it were me writing this code, I would install [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) and do this using a "real" HTML templating language (which would have loop and stuff, which would make the HTML template easier to read).

Comment: I've tried wrapping the variables in string and am getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 3471: ordinal not in range(128). Really wish I would have used jinja2 now that I've looked at it. May switch but still curious about this problem.

Comment: +1 for Jinja2. If you're dealing with more than one situation like this one, a real templating engine will save you a lot of time.